# I can't log into my VPS. Email server up, SSH down, HTTP down

Tags: ssh, vps, centos6, server-crashes

I can't log into my VPS. SSH gives the following error. All the web servers are down. They connect, but do not serve content. However, the email server is still working. The server responds to ping as well. Burst.net support is worthless and unresponsive. Burst.net has a button for 'serial console', but it throws a Java applet ClassNotFound exception. They also have a button for 'reboot', but that didn't help.

```
$ ssh  -v 308321.oliveyou.net
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 308321.oliveyou.net [184.82.92.84] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/Chloe/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer


$ telnet 308321.oliveyou.net 25
Trying 184.82.92.84...
Connected to 308321.oliveyou.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.kizbit.com ESMTP Postfix
HELO kizbit.com
250 mail.kizbit.com
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get on, what kind of advice would you expect from us?

I typically see this behavior when the system is running out of RAM.  A reboot *should* fix that assuming it's not loading something that eats up a lot of RAM immediately on start; a bad mysql.conf can do this.

That said:

If you can't get on the console and you cannot log in to the system remotely **only** your provider is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing you need to move away from Burst.net because you have vps not dedicated
and if support team not good , and your expecting problems in your vps , your in trouble

2nd , i think Burst.net  provide vps clients with access to vePortal panel
so you can reboot your vps and manage it remotely ,

if not , i am afraid , no solution rather than contacting them